# Why can I only hit my react/webpack app at root (/)?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I spent today setting up `react-transform` with the `hot-loader`.  I have an app with 2 routes, `/` and `/reports`.  I can hit the `/` and then click on a `Link` to take me to `/reports` and it works fine, but it I try to go to `/reports` straight away, then I get a `404`.  Here is my `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        app: [
            './App.js',
            'webpack-hot-middleware/client'
        ],
        vendors: vendors
    },
    output: {
        filename: './bundle.[hash].js',
        chunkFilename: './[id].[hash].js',
        path: __dirname + '/dist'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.ejs'
        }),

        new CommonsPlugin({
            name: 'vendors',
            filename: 'vendors.js',
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),

        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'], {
            root: __dirname,
            verbose: true,
            dry: false
        }),

        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),

        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ]
};
```

And here is my `server.js`

```
var app = express();

var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler));
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
app.use(express.static('/'));

app.listen(3000);
```

I have tried adding a route with

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});
```

But `/dist/index.html` is not there because of the `hot-loader` has it in memory.  The exact error is

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/jason/Developer/stack/webapp/dist/index.html'
   at Error (native)
```

What do I need to change in my configuration?

Comment: The 404 is from express or a configured 404 route in the front?

Comment: It is from `express`.  I added the error message above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `express` server was set up wrong.  I added this route to `express`:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    var memoryFs = compiler.outputFileSystem;
    var index = path.join(webpackConfig.output.path, 'index.html');
    var html = memoryFs.readFileSync(index);
    res.end(html)
});
```

And now I am working perfectly.